# ruby on rails - Undefined conversion when inputting cyrillic symbols with acts_as_taggable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
gem 'acts_as_taggable_on'
gem 'activeadmin'

...

ActiveAdmin.register Article do
...
    form do |f|
        f.inputs do
            f.input :tag_list 
        end
    end
end
```

I'm trying to input as tag word "статья", but in return:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in Admin::ArticlesController#create
"\xD1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Looked everywhere but couldn't find suitable answer. What should I do to remove this error?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that with other input fields like title or article_body it's fine to pass cyrillic symbols. So I guess it has something with acts_as_taggable gem.

Comment: What is your rails and ruby versions?

Comment: ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it really was problem with acts_as_taggable gem.
In my research through internets and rails console I found out that problem was during saving to database. Conversion failed because it was converting some unknown encoding to binary format and sqlite3 was unable to save that to string column. So I redacted gem file as follows

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/acts_as_taggable_on-3.0.0.rc2/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb

...
def as_8bit_ascii(string)
    if defined?(Encoding)
        string.to_s.force_encoding('UTF-8') #It was BINARY previously
    else
        string.to_s.mb_chars
    end
end
```

And now it works!

**UPDATE**

It's better not to patch source code but to apply it to your application, I guess. So, to apply so called monkey patch I did following.

1) Created file tag.rb in config/initializers

2) Copied code from gem and cut/paste it just as follows (learned by experiment and googling on monkey patches)

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
    class << self
    private
        def as_8bit_ascii(string)
            if defined?(Encoding)
                string.to_s.force_encoding('UTF-8') #It was BINARY previously
            else
                string.to_s.mb_chars
            end
        end
    end
end
```